# Capacity approximations by sets with regular boundary

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, potential-theory, regularity

Suppose I have a continuous, compactly supported function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and I define the set $S := f^{-1}([a,\infty)) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ for some $a > 0$.  It is a compact set and therefore its logarithmic capacity is well defined.  Let's denote $C(E)$ the logarithmic capacity of a capacitable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

What conditions on $f$ ensure the existence of a sequence of capacitable sets with regular (say Lipschitz) border $S_{n} \subset S$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} C(S_{n}) = C(S)$?  In particular, is continuity  a sufficient condition? Does more regularity help?